# Vue component: need the checked value

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have installed the [PrettyCheckbox](https://lokesh-coder.github.io/pretty-checkbox/) and it works fine. BUT I need the value if the checkbox is marked. Please see the picture. I can see that if the checkbox is checked I have the true value otherwise its false.But how can I get the value

Here you see the false value if the checkbox is **NOT CHECKED**
[image]

Here you see the true value when the checkbox is **CHECKED**
[image]

So my question is, how do I get the value in my vue component, I have tried this `{{m_checked}}`, but did not work for me.

**NOW IT IS WORKING**

My issue is that I can't access the m_checked because its forbidden outside the plugin. So I need to use the v-model='check'
It works now. I have inserted `v-model="check"`
My code looks like this

```
<p-check class="p-svg p-plain p-bigger p-smooth" v-model="check">
      <img slot="extra" class="svg" src="/img/icons/accept.png">
      Interested => {{check}}
</p-check>
```

values

```
data: function () {
            return {
                check: false
            }
        },
```

Comment: You need to use `v-model`: [it's well-documented on their VueJS plugin docs](https://github.com/hamed-ehtesham/pretty-checkbox-vue#usage). The `m_checked` value is only available internally as the component's own data, so you can't access it from the outside. Also... please include a minimal, concrete, and verifiable example.

Comment: Great. Thanks for your help :D

Comment: I have updated the question. Was that what you try to tell with "include a minimal, concrete, and verifiable example" ? @Terry

Comment: Good that you got it sorted out now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NOW IT IS WORKING

My issue is that I can't access the m_checked because its forbidden outside the plugin. So I need to use the v-model='check' It works now. I have inserted v-model="check" My code looks like this

```
<p-check class="p-svg p-plain p-bigger p-smooth" v-model="check">
      <img slot="extra" class="svg" src="/img/icons/accept.png">
      Interested => {{check}}
</p-check>
```

values

```
data: function () {
            return {
                check: false
            }
        },
```